# How to display multi-line string without expand the cell

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I want to display a multi-line string in a propertyGrid in C#.
It exists a `MultilineStringEditor` Type allowing to display it but while the cell is not expanded the string is not fully visible.

In VB, it exists settings of property grid named `VariableItemsHeight` and  `Item.MultiLinesCount` allowing to do what i really want but i have not found the same settings in C#. What is the way to do the same thing in C#?

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see `VariableItemsHeight` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) things like this would not be different from c# to vb

Comment: In fact, it was refering this article [link] (http://www.codejock.com/support/articles/com/propertygrid/pg_1.asp) but it is exact that is an old version of VB 6.0.